# Draw the lambda blazon

Tags: code-golf, string, ascii-art

To celebrate the 2497th anniversary of the Greek victory at Salamis in 480 BC. Draw the lambda blazon.

The lambda blazon was the lambda painted on greek shields like so:

[image: images of red capital lambda on circular white and gold shield backgrounds]

**Puzzle:** Given a positive odd integer n, produce an ascii art image of the above shield.

**Specifications:**

**n=1:**

```
( /\ )
```

**n=3:**

```
(   /\   )
|  /  \  | 
( /    \ )
```

**n=5**

```
(     /\     )
|    /  \    |
|   /    \   |
|  /      \  |
( /        \ )
```

**Graph:**
**n=3**

```
          2|   (   /\   )
y-axis    1|   |  /  \  | 
          0|   ( /    \ )
               ___________  
               0123456789

                 x-axis
```

**Description:**

There should be exactly *n* `\` characters and *n* `/` characters. The `/`s and `\`s should not touch the edge of the shield. The bottom and top corners of the shield will be denoted with a `(` or `)` unless *n*=1 where there will be one `)` and one `(`. There will always be one space between the bottom corners and the lambda, increasing by 1 with the y axis until `y + 1 == n`. Non corners of the shield side will be denoted with `|`. There is no shield top.

Comment: can you add the output for `n=5` or `n=7`

Comment: @Rod added n=5 for you

Comment: Why downvote? (2 more to go)

Comment: @user202729 im confused what you mean.

Comment: I'm asking the downvoters, not you. Sorry if it is unclear.

Comment: @user202729 what do you mean 2 more to go?

Comment: SE has comment character restriction, which force comments to be at least 15 characters.

Comment: Why couldn't you have waited 3 years to post it for the 2.5k'th anniversary ;-;

Comment: @HyperNeutrino I literally googled "today in history" and found that to make a golf out of :)

Comment: Would these shields have been used in a naval battle?

Comment: Its very possible, much of the combat was spear throwing and many used these type of shields in conjunction with their spears.

Comment: That's what I get for playing Age of Empires... they just launched their giant projectiles at each other

Comment: Why only odd integers? :o

Answer (score 8):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal),  <s>17</s>  13 bytes

*Thanks to @Neil for saving 4 bytes!*

```
(↙↓⊖θＭ↑(→↗Ｎ‖Ｍ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/1/jUdvMR22TH3VNO7fj/Z61j9omAkUmPWqb/n7PukcN04BC//8bAwA)

**Explanation:**

```
(↙                // Print '(' and move one step down and to the left.
  ↓⊖θ             // Print n-1 '|'s downwards.
     Ｍ↑          // Move one step up.
        (→        // Print '(' and move one step to the right.
          ↗Ｎ      // Print n '/'s towards the upper right corner.
            ‖Ｍ    // Mirror the left half to produce the right half.
```

Comment: `⊖` saves you a byte, and half of your `Ｍ`s are unnecessary.

Comment: Also, your `Ｉθ` can be `Ｎ` to save another byte.

Comment: Summing up Neil's suggestions, **[13 bytes](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/1/jUdvMR22TH3VNO7fj/Z61j9omAkUmPWqb/n7PukcN04BC//8bAwA)**

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Thanks, but I got around to doing those already.

Comment: It's small, but I believe in your explanation `(→` should mean "... and move one step to the *right*"

Answer (score 6):

## [SOGL V0.12](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL), <s>17</s> 14 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL/blob/master/chartable.md)

```
┐*ƨ(Κm«@.╚┼┼╬³
```

[Try it Here!](https://dzaima.github.io/SOGLOnline/?code=JXUyNTEwKiV1MDFBOCUyOCV1MDM5QW0lQUJALiV1MjU1QSV1MjUzQyV1MjUzQyV1MjU2QyVCMw__,inputs=Mw__)

Explanation:

```
example input: 3
┐*              push a string of input amount of "|"                      "|||"
  ƨ(            push "("                                                  "|||", "(("
    Κ           prepend that to the vertical bar string                   "((|||"
     m          mold that string as the input (remove excess characters)  "((|"
      «         put the first character at the end                        "(|("
       @        push a space                                              "(|(", " "
        .╚      create a diagonal of input length                         "(|(", " ", ["  /", " / ", "/  "]
          ┼┼    append those three horizontally together                  ["(   /", "|  / ", "( /  "]
            ╬³  palindromize that all
```

Answer (score 4):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>103</s> 96 bytes

- Saved seven bytes thanks to [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat).

```c
f(n,j,b){for(j=n;j--;printf("%c%*c%*c%*c\n","|("[b],j+2,47,n+n-j+~j,92,j+2,"|)"[b=j<1|n-2<j]));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYxBCsIwEEWvUgKFGTMBGwSRNBfIFbQLG4l0wKkUd0avHlu18Ffv8V801xhLSSDE1OMzjROwF8fGuPs0yCOBqmO9@e8kilQGdew7Ym1ptyfRYli/mQ72i1TGWXtumyzGttwhule5nQeB8Ou7YJqtwzUvla/qy1IOSAmC1kirm@ny/gA)

Comment: We excuse the main and includes now? This community has changed.

Comment: @AlecTeal It is acceptable to write a function that performs the specified task rather than a full program. Includes in general _do_ count towards the byte count, some C compilers, however, attempt to guess a function definition if no matching includes are present.

Comment: Think you crossed out the wrong number, chief

Comment: @Veskah True. ._.

Answer (score 3):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 41 bytes

```
.+
$* 
 
( $'/$`$`\$' )¶
G`.
sT`()`|`¶.*¶
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P9fT5tLRUuBS4FLQ0FFXV8lQSUhRkVdQfPQNi73BD2u4pAEDc2EmoRD2/S0Dm37/98UAA) Explanation:

```
.+
$*
```

Convert to unary, but using spaces.

```
 
( $'/$`$`\$' )¶
```

Use the match prefix and suffix operators to generate a series of lines with increasing amounts of centre space on each line.

```
G`.
```

However, there's an extra blank line, which throws off the final transliteration, so delete it here.

```
sT`()`|`¶.*¶
```

On all lines except the first and last, change the `()`s to `|`s.

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 91 + 1 (`-p`) = 92 bytes

```perl
$_='('.($s=$"x($q=$_))."/\\$s)";while(--$q){say;y/()/|/;s| /|/ |;s|\\ | \\|}s/\|/(/;s/\|/)/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FclBCsIwEEDRq4Qw0MkimYp0FXIEbzBQXBQsFJs6gi2OV3eMq/fh1@mxDGYwlg67hCAF/I6wFRhDSJ6YQYLPr9u8TBgjbOEt1yMfhIGUsqhrOG3B7NQx60eIlbC9v4HMzt@1Puf1LhYvQ@pPvcX6Aw)

Answer (score 2):

## [Java (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), <s>200</s> <s>190</s> 170 bytes

```java
n->{for(char i=0,s[];i<n;s[-~n-i]=47,s[2+n+i]=92,s[0]=i<1|i>n-2?40:'|',s[3+n+n]=i<1|i++>n-2?41:'|',System.out.println("".valueOf(s).replace('\0',' ')))s=new char[4+n+n];}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RZA9b4MwEIZ3fsUpCyCCRdJIUUtIh04dqg4ZKYPrOOSoOSPbpKqS9K9Th1L1ptP73tdzDT/xVHeSmv3HgG2njYPGa6x3qNihJ@FQE3vSZPtWmjwIuv5doQChuLXwwpHgHIAP67jz@l/l5pmcrKXZQmeQ3O6IUu2hgIHS7fmgTSSO3AAW2dyWVY4bym2ZflOKVbFae22ZUOLz@6XPs6rAzeKCW0qXj6vsIbyEXr3zFTQ5SfLrLUZv92WdbJnuHRuXK4pmM3biqpevh8jGzMhOcSGj8C0L5yGEcRzbguQn3I4qV@Pg/Dp42hvZRDwBnjTuofXc0c754XVZATe1jac3jA3/xIwLITsXreN8tK/BNRh@AA)

Comment: [167 bytes](https://tio.run/##TZA9b8IwEIb3/IoTSxKFWClFQm0wHTp1qDowphlcx8BR5xzZDlUF9K@nJgK1t9373tdze3EQuekU7ZvPAdvOWA/7oLHeo2abnqRHQ@zZkOtbZcso6voPjRKkFs7Bq0CCYwQhnBc@6LfK5Qt5tVV2BZ1F8usdKt0Ah4Hy1XFjbCJ3wgLyYuqqusQlla7KfyjHms8XQcsyDGnNH2YhKWqOy9kJV5ye5sVjfIqDeJ9RRv@Nu9FYfzuvWmZ6z8bNmpLJhB2E7tXbJnEps6rTQqokfi/iaQxxmqaOk/qCy0XVfJxanoeAesG64l7pDgYbaAN0svZh@LaqQditS68/GBv@cJmQUnU@WaTlaJ@jczT8Ag "Java (OpenJDK 8) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyth](https://pyth.readthedocs.io), 43 bytes

This is quite gigantic given that it's been done on mobile :-/

```
j_m++++++@"(|"J!/,1QdK*;d\/*;y-Qd\\K@")|"JS
```

**[Try it online!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=j_m%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%40%22%28%7C%22J%21%2F%2C1QdK%2a%3Bd%5C%2F%2a%3By-Qd%5C%5CK%40%22%29%7C%22JS&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=1%0A2%0A3%0A4%0A5&debug=0)**

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 85 bytes

```python
n=a=input()
while a:print'(|'[1<a<n]+a*' '+'/'+(n-a)*'  '+'\\'+a*' '+')|'[1<a<n];a-=1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P8820TYzr6C0REOTqzwjMydVIdGqoCgzr0Rdo0Y92tAm0SYvVjtRS11BXVtdX11bI083URPIA3FjYtRhMppwtdaJuraG//@bAgA)

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 153 bytes

```r
function(n){s=2*n+4
m=matrix('|',s,n)
m[3:s-1,]=' '
m[cbind(5:s-2,c(n:1,1:n))]=1
m[1,c(1,n)]='('
m[s,c(1,n)]=')'
m[m>0]=rep(c('/','\\'),n)
rbind(m,'\n')}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bc0xDsIwDAXQPadgsw1BkJYulcxFaIcSWqlDTNUUCQk4e3BYkBDjf/625zRwGm7il/EqKPSIXKxlczCBQ7fM4x3hCTZaIRNOZR23zrYMK9Dkz6NcsFIrrEepnXW1ELXsdOiUnG5pGXM5fjPlHI77lud@Qo@wAwtNA5SfzJ@jQUGAXinwgI6M7xa12E8MQMZkLf9q9avJvQE)

Answer (score 2):

### Batch, 218 bytes

```
@echo off
set s=
for /l %%i in (1,1,%1)do call set s= %%s%%
set s=%s%/\%s%
echo (%s%)
for /l %%i in (2,1,%1)do call:l %1 %%i
exit/b
:l
set s=%s: /=/ %
set s=%s:\ = \%
if %1==%2 (echo ^(%s%^))else echo ^|%s%^|
```

As if `|`s weren't bad enough, `()`s don't work well with `if`...`else`.

Answer (score 2):

## 05ab1e (27 bytes)

```
F"|("0NQ¹<NQ~èð¹N-×'/ðN×J∞,
```

[try it online](https://tio.run/##AS8A0P8wNWFiMWX//0YifCgiME5Rwrk8TlF@w6jDsMK5Ti3Dlycvw7BOw5dK4oieLP//Mw)

explanation

```
F                                                #Loop n times        
 |("0NQ¹<NQ~è                                    #Use ( or |        
             ð¹N-×                               #put spaces (1)        
                  '/                             #put /                
                    ðN×                          #put more space                
                       J∞,                       #reverse image
```

Comment: I think `'/¹N-ú` is a byte shorter than `ð¹N-×'/`.

Comment: Nice approach, but there are a few things to golf. One is what _@Neil_ suggested above. In addition: `"|("` can be `„|(` (there are builtins for 1, 2, and 3-char strings being `'`, `„` and `…` respectively); and `0NQ¹<NQ~` can be `Î‚Nåè` (`Î` seems to be bugged in the legacy version of TIO, but it does work in the latest version of 05AB1E, in which case you'll also have to replace `∞` with `º`). So in total (**21 bytes**): `F„|(Î‚Nåè'/¹N-úðN×Jº,` [Try it online](https://tio.run/##ASwA0/9vc2FiaWX//0bigJ58KMOO4oCaTsOlw6gnL8K5Ti3DusOwTsOXSsK6LP//Mw).

Answer (score 2):

## [Funky](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/Funky), 101 bytes

```
n=>for(i=0;i<n;i++)print(((c=(i==n-1)or!i)?"(":"|")..(s=" "*n-i).."/"..(" "*i*2).."\\"..s..c?")":"|")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcuxCoNAEIThPk@RTLWreIkRm5iNL2InLCyBVU4tAnn3yx1pBr4fRg9/f5JKcnnpEsnkNtjTB6trXqP5TkSz5CzetLzEi/EIwgNfcAi0Cc6ovLEMXJFLsVX34mnKYQthHsH/R1Jq@aTUlek5/QA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 90 bytes

```python
n=input()
for i in range(n):m=-~i%n<2;s=' '*(n-i);print'|('[m]+s+'/'+'  '*i+'\\'+s+'|)'[m]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FckxDoMwEATAnldcg9bGQlEoAb8EKFIk4QoWy5gCCeXrDrQz4UjzyiZnemXYk7HFZ42iopT44vdtaNvF1z8t2Tfd5iGoDGu1XYjKhNNgWCa3OTzgINeqwzjiltPel/PzDw)

-1 thanks to [ovs](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/64121/ovs).

Comment: fails for `n=1`, but can be fixed by replacing `i%~-n<1` with `-~i%n<2`

Comment: @Rod thanks, fixed

Comment: [90 bytes](https://tio.run/##FckxDoMwEATAnldcg9bGQlEoAb8EKFIk4QoWy5gCCeXrDrQz4UjzyiZnemXYk7HFZ42iopT44vdtaNvF1z8t2Tfd5iGoDGu1XYjKhNNgWCa3OTzgINeqwzjiltPel/PzDw): `'<space>'*i*2` -> `'<space><space>'*i`

Comment: @ovs @_@ why didn't I think of that

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, <strike>110 bytes</strike> 93 bytes

```
b=c=int(input())*2
d,e='/\\'
while b:print('(|%%ss)|'[2<b<c::2]%f' {d+e:^{c}} ');d+='  ';b-=2
```

Answer (score 1):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 188 bytes

```cs
n=>{int y=0,i=-1;var s="";while(y<n){var r=new char[n*2+4];r[n+1-y]='/';r[n+2+y]='\\';if(y<2|y++>n-2)i++;r[0]="(|("[i];r[n*2+3]=")|)"[i];s+=new string(r)+"\n";}return s.Replace("\0"," ");}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY8xb8IwEIXn5lecvMSuCYXQqoMxS6VOrVSVoQNhiIzbnJReKtuAopDfnpogVra79927u2d8Zhpnh71H@oF164P9VYmpS@/ho0t8KAMaeN2TWSKFCfjg4uAK1hXaegcaBtKrLiJo9WyCOpurQ@nAa8bUscLa8nZJojtrTpM9gqlKt6H7XD5uVSzkPGu3On1IxyaX56YoUoXf0ZifWilXlOUCpYwDs61m/MTZBkdvXLKIijiJUfFyPHD5kDshWUFM9c6GvSPw00/7V5fGclbM2IQBE6ofVHKNeGhwB@8lEhdJl9y9NOSb2k6/HAb7hmT5JTGfC6Fu4MVt/HQbP59xn/TDPw)

#### Degolfed

```cs
n=>{
    int y=0,i=-1;
    var s="";

    while(y<n){
        var r=new char[n*2+4];
        r[n+1-y]='/';
        r[n+2+y]='\\';

        if(y<2 | y++>n-2)
            i++;

        r[0] = "(|("[i];
        r[n*2+3] = ")|)"[i];

        s += new string(r)+"\n";
    }

    return s.Replace("\0"," ");
}
```

Comment: [185 bytes](https://tio.run/##fY/BToQwEIbP8hSTXra1sAKrMbEUDyaeNDHuwcPCgXSr2wQH03bXEODZkWXjldv8@b6ZzK9cpBqrx6Mz@AXb1nn9LQJVV87BWxc4X3mj4PmIKjPoQ3DeTmIO24PR9R4kjCjz7lRZcJIQ8dlYOnnQyjg0MkpEm6FgM7cS9S@oQ2V3eJ3y21JMA0@itpSrm9UcUn4ORXFOcSkJ7SnZGS7bLO1bznOM0sfkIZ43pxObSWE9m5RSOD6fv7xHLeOkQCIGq/3RIrj1u/6pK6UpKWISEiBMDKMI/vudGrOH18ogZUEXXD016Jparz@s8frFoKaXujRhTCzgzTK@W8b3ZzwEw/gH "C# (.NET Core) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell),  <s>93</s> <s>91</s> <s>90</s> 89 bytes

<sup>-2 Thanks to ASCII-only for pointing out extra parens</sup>
<sup>-1 Thanks to Mazzy for tweaking swap logic</sup>

```powershell
param($n)0..--$n|%{"|("[!($x=($n-$_)*$_)]+($y=" "*($n-$_+1))+"/"+"  "*$_+"\$y"+"|)"[!$x]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfmvkmZb/b8gsSgxV0MlT9NAT09XVyWvRrVaqUZDKVpRQ6XCFiiuqxKvqQXEsdoaKpW2SgpKWhBBbUNNTW0lfSVtJQWgGJCvFKNSCeTVaAL1qlTE1v6v5VJTSVMwBJNGYNIYTJr@BwA)

<s>Trying to tweak that `$x=` bit. There's probably a smarter way to get the 1st and last line out in a few less bytes.</s> There is a better `$x=` but it isn't much cheaper.

Comment: 89 bytes: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfmvkmZb/b8gsSgxV0MlT9NAT09XVyWvRrVaqUZDKVpRQ6XCFiiuqxKvqQXEsdoaKpW2SgpKWhBBbUNNTW0lfSVtJQWgGJCvFKNSCeTVaAL1qlTE1v6v5VJTSVMwBJNGYNIYTJr@BwA "PowerShell – Try It Online")

Answer (score 0):

## [Canvas](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas), 12 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas/blob/master/files/chartable.md)

```
┤|×(ｅ⟳ ＋╴／＋║
```

[Try it here!](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=JXUyNTI0JTdDJUQ3JTI4JXVGRjQ1JXUyN0YzJTIwJXVGRjBCJXUyNTc0JXVGRjBGJXVGRjBCJXUyNTUx,i=NQ__,v=0)

Explanation:

```
┤             decrease the input by 2
 |×           repeat "|" vertically - if the amount is -1 (for input of 1), ir just removes the item currently
   (          push "("
    ｅ        encase in that parentheis - if that first string isn't there, currently it just fails doing anything and leaves the parenthesis on the stack
     ⟳       rotate clockwise
       ＋     append horizontally a space
        ╴／   get a diagonal the length of the input
          ＋  append it horizontally to the current result
           ║  and palindromize horizontally with 0 overlap
```